# Uncaught DOMException: This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I already upload and get the list of product successful but Update product show for me an error. **I do not know how to update my image and data on Firebase in Reactjs.**

**This is my code in `ProductForm.js`**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Gongcha from '../asses/gongcha.jpg'

const ProductForm = (props) => {
  const initialFieldValues = {
    image: '',
    name: '',
    category: '',
    price: ''
  };

  var [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);
  var [imageFile, setImageAsFile] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentId == '') setValues({ ...initialFieldValues });
    else
      setValues({
        ...props.productObjects[props.currentId],
      });
  }, [props.currentId, props.productObjects]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    var { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addOrEdit(values, imageFile);
  };
  const handleImageAsFile = (e) => { 
    console.log("file image",e);
    const image = e.target.files[0]
    setImageAsFile(imageFile => (image))
}

  return (
    <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group input-group">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <i className="fas fa-image"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="file"
          name="image"
          placeholder="Image"
          value={values.image}
          onChange={handleImageAsFile}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group input-group col-md-6">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <div className="input-group-text">
              <i className="fas fa-mug-hot"></i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <input
            className="form-control"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group input-group col-md-6">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <div className="input-group-text">
              <i className="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            name="category"
            placeholder="Category"
            value={values.category}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group input-group">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <i className="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="price"
          placeholder="Price"
          value={values.price}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="submit"
          value={props.currentId == '' ? 'Save' : 'Update'}
          className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

And this is the **table, which the place I showed all list of product and also Action (Edit and Delete)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Imgage } from 'react-bootstrap'
import ProductForm from './ProductForm';
import { DB, Storage } from '../firebase';    

const Products = () => {
  var [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState('');
  var [productObjects, setProductObjects] = useState({});
  const [ImageAsUrl, setImageAsUrl] = useState()


  useEffect(() => {
    DB.ref().child('products').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null) {
        setProductObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const addOrEdit = (obj, image_url) => {

    let upload = Storage.ref().child(`product-img/${image_url.name}`).put(image_url)
    upload.on('state_changed',
      (snapShot) => {

        console.log(snapShot)
      }, (err) => {

        console.log(err)
      }, () => {

        Storage.ref('product-img').child(image_url.name).getDownloadURL()
          .then(fireBaseUrl => {

            DB.ref().child('products').push({ name: obj.name, image: fireBaseUrl, category: obj.category, price: obj.price }, (err) => {

              if (err) console.log(err);
              else setCurrentId('');
            })

          })
      })

    console.log("log imgage link", ImageAsUrl);
  };

  const onDelete = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')) {
      DB.ref().child(`products/${id}`).remove((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId('');
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Products Manager</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <ProductForm {...{ currentId, productObjects, addOrEdit }} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <table className="table table-borderless table-stripped">
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(productObjects).map((key) => (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{productObjects[key].image}</td>
                  <td>{productObjects[key].name}</td>
                  <td>{productObjects[key].category}</td>
                  <td>{productObjects[key].price}</td>
                  <td className="bg-light">
                    <a
                      type="button"
                      className="btn text-primary"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setCurrentId(key);
                      }}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a
                      type="button"
                      className="btn text-danger"
                      onClick={() => {
                        onDelete(key);
                      }}
                    >
                      <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

This is an Error show for me when I clicked `Update` icon:

[image]

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem? I really do not know how to fix it. Please? Your help is my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

As the error explains, you can not set a value property on an input / file element. Short example:

```
<input type="file" value="this throws an error" />
```

That means, you can not "pre-populate" the input field if the user already uploaded a file. You could show the file (if it's an image) and add a delete option (e.g button) next to it.

Comment: How can I update that product, also the data of that product? If I do as you said, it will add new data not update the old data. Can you help me with that

Comment: If you would like to send one request, `multipart/form-data` is an option - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#A_special_case_sending_files

otherwise just upload the file via javascript (e.g. firebase offers simple methods here as well), retrieve the URL and save it with the rest.